# How to restart transaction after deadlocked or timed out in Java ?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, transactions, database-deadlocks

How to restart a transaction (so that it executes at least once) when we get:

> ( com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException:Deadlock found when trying to get lock; Try restarting transaction )  OR ( transaction times out ) ?

I'm using MySQL(innoDB ENGINE) and  Java.Please help and also link any useful resources or codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever you are catching such type of exception in your catch block

```
catch(Exception e){
if(e instanceof TransactionRollbackException){
 //Retrigger Your Transaction
   }
// log your exception or throw it its upto ur implementation
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is specific to deadlocks? I don't want to be caught in an endless loop if anything besides a deadlock can throw `TransactionRollbackException`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use plain JDBC, you have to do it manually, in a loop (and don't forget to check the pre-conditions every time.
If you use spring, "[How to restart transactions on deadlock/lock-timeout in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762870/how-to-restart-transactions-on-deadlock-lock-timeout-in-spring)" sould help.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.I'm using plain JDBC. Can you please give a sample code like for() { transaction } for checking pre-conditions.