# Trying to understand why @transactional(noROllBackFor .... is not working

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

I have some code that looks like this:

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = { CannotAcquireLockException.class, LockAcquisitionException.class })
public void deleteSomeData() {
    int backOffTime = 0;
    int fibonacci = 1;
    boolean executed = false;

    do {
        try {
            this.myDAO.deleteTheData();
            executed = true;
        } catch (RuntimeException rt) {
            int newBackoffTime = backOffTime + fibonacci;
            fibonacci = backOffTime;
            backOffTime = newBackoffTime;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(backOffTime * 100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    } while (!executed);
}
```

This is running within a Spring/JPA environment. The code is run by a number of Quartz driven tasks which fire at various times, sometimes all at the same time. Hence I'm trying to get around database (MySQL) deadlocks that are occurring by re-executing the update code after a delay if a dead lock exception is thrown.

I've been trying all sorts of things and reading lots of posts about transactions, deadlocks, etc.

The problem is that if `this.myDAO.deleteTheData();` throws a `CannotAcquireLockException` then the transaction is marked as needing to be rolled back. What I'm attempting to do is wait for a period of time and then attempt the update again. However this second attempt then fails due to to the rollback state. So I'm trying to stop the transaction being set as needing a rollback if this exception is thrown.

I'm not sure I've got all this right in my head and this code is not working. The transaction is still being marked as needing a rollback.

I could move the looping code out to the code that calls this method, which would remove the need to worry about the transaction, however that would involve a far amount of repeated code execution and I'd like to keep this as near to the DB as possible.

Any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong with this?

Comment: Check out this answer, it might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762870/how-to-restart-transactions-on-deadlock-lock-timeout-in-spring

Comment: Do you have `@Transactional` annotations in your DAO?

Comment: Remove the `@Transactional` from the dao. Also instead of implementing your own, I would suggest using [`spring-retry`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry).

Comment: There's no @Transactioal in the DAO. Ill try spring-retry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading the answers on my original post I switched to using [Spring Retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry) and was able to remove all my looping code. The method now looks like this:

```
@Transactional
@ConcurrentDBUpdateRetryPolicy
public void deleteSomeData() {
    this.myDAO.deleteTheData();
}
```

With a custom annotation which defines the retry policy I want to employ. You don't need to do a custom annotation, but doing it this way allows you to centralise a common retry definition. Here's the custom annotation:

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Retryable(
   include = CannotAcquireLockException.class, 
   maxAttempts = 10, 
   backoff = @Backoff(delay = 500, maxDelay = 10000, multiplier = 2, random = true)
)
public @interface ConcurrentDBUpdateRetryPolicy {}
```

So far this has been working very smoothly. So thanks to the guys who suggested it and thanks to the authors of Spring Retry.